# When do I have to set a seed?

Tags: r, simulation, random-seed

I think this is a very basic question

I am doing simulations, so I make functions to recreate for example a random walk, which mathematically takes this form:

[image]

so to simulate it I make my function:

```
ar_1 <- function(iter, y0, sigma_e){
  
  e <- rnorm(iter, sd = sigma_e)
  
  y <- numeric(iter)
  y[1] <- y0
  
  for(t in 2:iter){
    y[t] = y[t-1]+e[t]
  }
  
  result <- data.frame(iteration  = seq(1,iter), y = y)
  
  print(plot(result$iteration, result$y, type="l"))
  
  return(result)
}

try1 <- ar_1(iter = 100, y0 = 2, sigma_e = 0.0003)
```

So the thing is the `e` vector takes random numbers.

I want to replicate the same graph and values wherever, so I know I gotta use a seed.

**So my question is:** does the seed goes inside the function or at the very start of the script?

Furthermore, I would want to know why.

Comment: Does your code call the function more than once? If so, then you should set the seed in the function. If the seed is set once at the start of the script, it will only "persist" for the first call to `rnorm()`.

Comment: This worked a lot, maybe do you want to put this comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `set.seed` once at the top of the script, the seed will remain set until the first call to `rnorm`. Subsequent calls to functions that require a random seed will not use the initial seed.

So really the answer is: do you intend to call the function more than once? If so, then set the seed inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need a `for` loop in your function.  Because R is vectorized, loops can ussually be avoided.  Random walk values can be calculated using the base R `cumsum` function.  For example:

```
set.seed(7)
y1 <- pi
rand_vals <- rnorm(10, 0, 5)
path <- c(y1, rand_vals)
walk <- cumsum(path)
rand_vals
 [1] 11.4362358 -5.9838584 -3.4714626 -2.0614648 -4.8533667 -4.7363997  3.7406967 -0.5847761  0.7632881 10.9498905
path
 [1]  3.1415927 11.4362358 -5.9838584 -3.4714626 -2.0614648 -4.8533667 -4.7363997  3.7406967 -0.5847761  0.7632881
[11] 10.9498905
walk
 [1]  3.141593 14.577828  8.593970  5.122507  3.061043 -1.792324 -6.528724 -2.788027 -3.372803 -2.609515  8.340376
```